# How could I skew a function of a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm currently trying to make a program that is a visualization of the central limit theorem, where taking a large enough smaple will lead to an approximate mean of the popularion that is normally distributed. For the program, it would be really nice if a variable could be changed from perhaps -1 to 1 that skews a normalized curve. Right now I have the function for the curve itself :
$$
f(x) =  e^{ \frac{ x^{2} }{2} }
$$

So it would be nice if I could take some number between -1 and 1 and be able to skew the graph left or right so that it transforms like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r8t8.jpg), where the black curve is the original normalized curve and the colored graphs are the transformed curves. I'm not looking for any particular numbers, as I just need to get the skew in the function.
.

Thanks!

Comment: you can look into the skew normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution It is for example implemented in R (and probably other software packages)

Comment: @Dinoswarleafs The skew Normal distribution is good, and for visualization the idea of modulating by a CDF can be generalized easily. Are you still interested in an answer?